# TCP server madness - Slow and Merged data

Tags: java, performance, tcp, client-server

I recently started to make a 2d java game, now I began the TCP server, though the server runs insanely slow (Average of 2 seconds) and I can't figure out how to stop the input stream from metering all the data into one string. I would greatly appreciate it if someone is able to help me.

ServerCode:

```
package com.diedericksclan.main.network;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private ServerHandler server;
    private ServerSocket dataSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private InetSocketAddress address;
    private int megabyte = 1024 * 1024;
    private int dedicated = 1024;
    public int RAM = megabyte * dedicated;

    private WriteData send;
    private ReadData read;

    public ServerThread(ServerHandler server, String serverIP, int ram, int backlog) throws Exception {
        this.server = server;
        this.dedicated = ram;
        //System.out.println(serverIP);
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 2048;
        if(serverIP.contains(":")) {
            ip = serverIP.split(":")[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(serverIP.split(":")[1]);
        } else {
            ip = serverIP;
            port = 2048;
        }
        //System.out.println("Makin' the server");
        this.dataSocket = new ServerSocket(port, backlog, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
        this.address = new InetSocketAddress(dataSocket.getInetAddress(), port);
        this.send = new WriteData();
        this.read = new ReadData();
        //System.out.println("Makin' the data handlers");

        //System.out.println("Server has been made, details: " + address.getAddress() + ":" + address.getPort());
    }

    public ServerThread(ServerHandler server, String ip) throws Exception {
        this(server, ip, 1024, 0);
    }

    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("made");
        this.send.start();
        this.read.start();
        while(true) {
            try {
                socket = dataSocket.accept();
                socket.setReceiveBufferSize(megabyte);
                socket.setSendBufferSize(megabyte);
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress IPaddress, int port) {
        this.send.sendData(data, IPaddress, port);
    }

    public void serverShutdown() {
        try {
            this.dataSocket.close();
            if(this.socket != null) this.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class WriteData extends Thread {
        public WriteData() {}
        public void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress IPaddress, int port) {
            try {
                System.out.println("[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] Sending... " + new String(data));
                socket.getOutputStream().write(data);
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReadData extends Thread {
        public ReadData() {}
        public void run() {
            try {
                this.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] data;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    data = new byte[megabyte];
                    socket.getInputStream().read(data);

                    System.out.println("[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] Server has read, " + new String(data) + ", details: " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + ":" + socket.getLocalPort());

                    server.parsePacket(data, socket.getInetAddress(), socket.getPort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientCode:

```
package com.diedericksclan.main.network;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    private ClientHandler client;
    private Socket socket;
    private InetSocketAddress address;
    private int megabyte = 1024 * 1024;

    private WriteData send;
    private ReadData read;

    public ClientThread(ClientHandler client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2", 2048);
        socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.setSendBufferSize(megabyte);
            socket.setSendBufferSize(megabyte);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            socket.connect(address);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Made client");
        this.send = new WriteData();
        this.read = new ReadData();
        //System.out.println("Client has been made, details: " + socket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + socket.getLocalPort());
    }


    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("made");
        this.send.start();
        this.read.start();
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] data) {
        this.send.sendData(data);
    }

    public void serverShutdown() {
        try {
            this.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class WriteData extends Thread {
        public WriteData() {}
        public void sendData(byte[] data) {
            try {
                //System.out.println("[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] Sending... " + new String(data) + " to: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());
                socket.getOutputStream().write(data);
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReadData extends Thread {
        public ReadData() {}
        public void run() {
            byte[] data;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    data = new byte[megabyte];
                    socket.getInputStream().read(data);
                    System.out.println("[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] Server data recived, " + new String(data).trim());
                    client.parsePacket(data, socket.getInetAddress(), socket.getPort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did try to improve speed by making 2 separate threads for reading and writing data, in both the client and server, yet there was no improvement,

Comment: `"can't figure out how to stop the input stream from metering all the data into one string"` - That's how TCP works. Remember, **TCP is a *stream***. If you want discrete chunks (or "packets" - but not the same as IP packets), you need to implement this in your application layer.

Comment: Also, wots with the 'this.sleep(1000);' on client<>server thread startup?

Comment: I made the threads sleep whilst the socket was being initialized, otherwise in that small time I would have gotten a NullPointerException. @Jonathon Reinhart And yes I know tcp is a stream I was wondering if there is a way to stop the issue i stated. I used udp before as it was better but I couldn't portforward it. Just wondering how would I go about making it send packets? I do not know what the application layer is, sorry i'm a stupid kid.

Comment: Ths application layer is everything that you send across a TCP connection ([Transport Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)).

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart So basically I would have to create a queuing system for send data between server and clients?

Comment: Adding a queue system is a good idea, but that doesn't explain your issue.  I would write it first without queuing and only add it it when it working.  Don't forget that the socket buffers are queues already so adding queues on either side of two queues in the sockets can have its uses but I would start with something simple first.

Comment: Adding a sleep() is no way to fix the NPE. Find the problem, don't just apply a bandaid to hide the bleeding.

Comment: @EJP The problem is that the readData thread starts before the sockets are created, so making it sleep a second give the sockets enough time to be created, and don't say make the sockets first because I need to have this layout for purposes of my game.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems.

- you allow any number of threads to write to the same socket at the same time.  This makes developing a protocol very hard.
- you need a protocol so you know where a message starts and end. e.g. you send the length first.
- you ignore how many bytes where read.  The minimum will be 1 and you can get any number of messages up to the size of the buffer at once.  TCP is a stream protocol, not a messaging protocol.

If you have a reader and writer process on the same machine you should be able to get the latency to around 10 micro-seconds. (0.000010 seconds)

---

EDIT here is a simple example

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class PlainIOSample {
    static final int RUNS = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
        DataSocket ds = new DataSocket(new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort()));
        DataSocket ds2 = new DataSocket(ss.accept());

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
            // send a small message
            ds.write(new byte[64]);
            // receive the same message
            byte[] bytes = ds2.read();
            if (bytes.length != 64)
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Average time to send/recv was %.1f micro-seconds%n",
                time / RUNS / 1e3);
        ds.close();
        ds2.close();
    }

    static class DataSocket implements Closeable {
        private final DataOutputStream dos;
        private final DataInputStream dis;
        private final Socket socket;

        public DataSocket(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void write(byte[] message) throws IOException {
            synchronized (dos) {
                dos.writeInt(message.length);
                dos.write(message);
                dos.flush();
            }
        }

        public byte[] read() throws IOException {
            synchronized (dis) {
                int length = dis.readInt();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                dis.readFully(bytes);
                return bytes;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Average time to send/recv was 3.3 micro-seconds
```

Comment: What do you mean, the readers and writers are on the same machine, before I had it just like a normal tcp server, with one class to handle everything for the server and a class for client, but then data transfer took about 3 seconds, now they take about 1 to 2 seconds. Could you possible elaborate on your points or give me an example? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to write a test where one Socket sends a message to another Socket on the same machine and back again in about 20 micro-seconds.  I suggest you write this as a stand alone test. BTW you can do this in just one thread.  You should write your socket handling components as stand alone classes and test them thoroughly.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on youtube when I started with tcp, and it sent really fast like it is supposed to, but then when I added the game data it slowed down terribly, the only thing i can think of that could slow it down is that every second i send the players coords, but when I print lines in the console, it takes a second for the server to read the data to the byte[] and same for the client. Am i reading it wrong?

Comment: You couldn't be reading it so wrong as to cause a multi-second delay.  You can send a packet to Tokyo and back around the other way around the world in about 0.5 seconds. Most likely your delay is somewhere else.  This is why I suggest developers performance test their components to see how fast their components are.  If you performance tests show you socket data is fine, either your test are not realistic enough or your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks, just one question, does my byte[] being worth one megabyte affect the speed of the input stream writing to it?

Comment: @user2693587 Not if you reuse it.  Creating a new one every time is very expensive. To reuse it you can create one byte[] at the start for in and out and keep track of how much of the buffer you are using e.g. `out.write(bytes, 0, length)` and `int length = in.read(bytes);`

Comment: I have fixed it now, the problem was that I was create a megabyte worth of bytes in the array every time the server and client read data, these are the times now on average about 35 nanoseconds, is that good?  And crazily enough one message was sent in 17 nanoseconds! omg, i'm so happy. Thanks so much, it means a lot to me as not many people are willing to help me because i'm 13 years old. :( This really helped only for some reason my server can't handle 2 or more clients. I think i'll redo the multithreading system.